# Interbase и windows 7

Tags: interbase

Установил себе Interbase 7.5. Все отлично устанавливается. Система 7-ка х64.

Но interbase не запускается. Вообщем нет никаких признаков её работы. Ставил совместимости- не помогло.

В чем проблема, подскажите?

Comment: Может лучше firebird, он поновее будет?

Comment: Нет, именно interbase нужен :(

Comment: Вот это попробуй
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670104/interbase-and-bde-on-windows-7